# Validators not supporting for second pojo Address in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, annotations, validation

Validation is working fine for User class but not for address class

***Registration.java***

```
package com.semanticbits.controller;

import com.semanticbits.pojo.Address;
import com.semanticbits.pojo.User;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

 @Controller
 @RequestMapping("/register")
 public class RegistrationController {

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String showRegistrationForm(ModelMap map){

     User user=new User();

      user.setAddress(new Address());

      map.addAttribute("user", user);
      return "register";
}

//reference data

  @ModelAttribute("genderList")
  public List<String> showGenderOnForm(){

    List<String> genderList=new ArrayList<>();

    genderList.add("Select gender");
    genderList.add("Male");
    genderList.add("Female");

    return genderList;
 }


   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processRegistrationForm(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result) {

       validator.validate(user, result);
     //validator.validate(user.getAddress(), result);

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "register";
    }

    return "welcome";
}

}
```

***Address.java***

```
package com.semanticbits.pojo;

import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import org.springmodules.validation.bean.conf.loader.annotation.handler.NotBlank;
 import org.springmodules.validation.bean.conf.loader.annotation.handler.Size;

 @Embeddable
 public class Address {

 @NotBlank(message = "Please enter city")
 private String city;
 @NotBlank(message = "Please enter state")
 private String state;
 @NotBlank(message = "Please enter zip code")
 @Size(max = 6,min = 6,message = "Zip code should be of 6 digits only")
 private int zipCode;


 //setters and getters
```

}

**User.java**

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
    package com.semanticbits.pojo;

```
import com.semanticbits.pojo.Address;
import javax.persistence.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.springmodules.validation.bean.conf.loader.annotation.handler.Length;
import org.springmodules.validation.bean.conf.loader.annotation.handler.Max;
import org.springmodules.validation.bean.conf.loader.annotation.handler.Min;
import org.springmodules.validation.bean.conf.loader.annotation.handler.NotBlank;

@Entity
@Table
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int userId;

@NotBlank(message = "Please enter username")
@Length(min = 6,message ="Please enter minimum six characters" )
private String username;

@NotBlank(message = "Please enter password")
private String password;

@NotBlank(message = "Please enter your first name")
private String firstName;

@NotBlank(message ="Please enter your last name")
private String lastName;

@Min(value=18,message = "Age should be greater than 18")
@Max(value=100,message="Age should be less than 99")
private int age;
private String gender;

@Embedded
private Address address;



public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

}

***register.jsp***

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>  
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     <title>Login here</title>
     <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
     <style>
         .form-error-message{ font-weight: bold; color: red; }
         .errorblock {
            color: #000;
            background-color: #ffEEEE;
            border: 3px solid #ff0000;
            padding: 8px;
            margin: 16px;
         }
     </style>
  <body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="modal-form"/>
        <h1>Registration form</h1>




        <form:form commandName="user" action="register.htm" method="POST">
            <form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div" />

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td> Username :</td>
                    <td><form:input path="username"/></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="username" cssClass="form-error-message"/>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Password :</td>
                    <td><form:input path="password"/></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="password" cssClass="form-error-message"/>
                <tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Confirm Password :</td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="confirmPassword"/></td>
                <tr/>

                <tr>
                    <td>First Name :</td>
                    <td><form:input path="firstName"/></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="firstName" cssClass="form-error-message"/></td>
                <tr/>

                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name :</td>
                    <td><form:input path="lastName"/></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="lastName" cssClass="form-error-message"/></td>
                <tr/>

                <tr>
                    <td>Age :</td>
                    <td><form:input path="age"/></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="age" cssClass="form-error-message"/></td>
                <tr/>

                <tr>
                    <td>Gender :</td>
                    <td><form:select items="${genderList}" path="gender"/></td>
                <tr/>


                <tr>
                    <td>City :</td>
                    <td><form:input path="address.city"/></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="address.city" cssClass="form-error-message"/></td>
                <tr/>

                <tr>
                    <td>State :</td>
                    <td><form:input path="address.state"/></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="address.state" cssClass="form-error-message"/></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Zip Code :</td>
                    <td><form:input path="address.zipCode"/></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="address.zipCode" cssClass="form-error-message"/></td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>  <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme"/>Remember Me</td>
                    <td><input type="submit" class="btn-medium btn btn-info" value="Login"/></td>

                </tr>
            </form:form>
     </div>

   </div>

  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 </body>



</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using the JSR 303 annotations, try annotating the nested `Address` property in the `User` class as `@Valid`

***User.java***

```
@Embedded
@Valid
private Address address;
```

In the controller, you can also annotate your `User` ModelAttribute as `@Valid` so that validation will take place automatically.

***RegistrationController.java***

```
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processRegistrationForm(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid User user, BindingResult result) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "register";
    }

    return "welcome";
}
```

Alternatively you can write a custom validator which can validate both the `User` and nested `Address` object.

Here's a post with a worked example describing validation of embedded objects using `@Valid` http://www.openscope.net/2010/02/08/spring-mvc-3-0-and-jsr-303-aka-javax-validation/